# Sed or awk to replace a line in a block

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Input file contains:

```
[abc]  
para1=123  
para2=456  
para3=111  

[pqr]  
para1=333  
para2=765  
para3=1345  

[xyz]  
para1=888  
para2=236  
para3=964
```

Requirement of shell script is to replace the one parameter of particular block
Ex: Replace `para2=765` with `para2=999` of block `[pqr]`
Please help me how can I achieve this with `sed` or `awk` command.

Comment: What have you done yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
awk '/^\[pqr\]/ {sub(/^para2=.*/,"para2=999")}1' RS= ORS="\n\n" file
[abc]
para1=123
para2=456
para3=111

[pqr]
para1=333
para2=999
para3=1345

[xyz]
para1=888
para2=236
para3=964
```

By setting `RS` to nothing, you make `awk` work in block mode separated by blank lines.
Then make sure we are in correct block by search for block starting with `[pqr]`
In this block, change the data from `para2=765` to `para2=999`, then print it.

---

Another way to do it:

```
awk '/^\[pqr\]/ {f=1} f && sub(/^para2=.*/,"para2=999"){f=0}1' file
```

Set a flag if `pqr` is found, change the data if flag is true, reset the flag.

Comment: Thanks Jotne it helped. I was thinking what if I don't have the line separator between the block? How to substitute in that case?

Comment: @user3789290 use the last `awk` in my example. It does not need space, or other separators.

Comment: You need to anchor your REs or the above would replace `para2=76512345` with `para2=99912345`, for example. I suspect the OP just wants to replace the `para2=` line no matter what value it has though.

Comment: The `Another way to do it` will fail since the para2 line isn't immediately after the [pqr] line so you're setting f=0 before the sub() gets a chance. You'd need to write that as `awk '/^\[pqr\]/ {f=1} f && sub(/^para2=.*/,"para2=999"){f=0}1' file` but then also maybe take care to reset `f` when the next `[...]` pattern is found. Or you could use a counter to track the number of lines after a `[...]` line and replace the 2nd line instead of using a sub().

Comment: @EdMorton Clever way to use  `sub` as the true test, I would have done  `awk '/^\[pqr\]/ {f=1} f && /^para2/ {sub(/^para2=.*/,"para2=999");f=0}1'` yours is better, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Through sed another way,

```
$ sed -r ':l /^\[pqr\]/{:loop ;n;/^$/{b l};s/(para2=).*/\1999/g;b loop;}' file_name

b loop   - Using the looping concept getting the line one by one.
^\[pqr\] - If the corresponding pattern is found.
^$       - Represent new line only.
s/       - Replacement to particular pattern.
n        - For getting next line
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\[pqr\]/,/^\s*$/s/\(para2=\)[0-9]*/\1999/' file
```

Substitute the number following `para2=` within the block starting `[pqr]` to an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

THE idiomatic awk solution is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} $1=="[pqr]"{$3="para2=999"} 1' file
[abc]
para1=123
para2=456
para3=111

[pqr]
para1=333
para2=999
para3=1345

[xyz]
para1=888
para2=236
para3=964
```