# Sed replace after specific pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

Given this pattern :

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None //change this one
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Running `$ sed -e 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/i' file` will change all instance of `AllowOverride`

How can i change the `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` for `<Directory /var/www/>`

Comment: This you should have found by using search.  It has been answered here several times.

Comment: @Jotne have you managed to find a suitable duplicate?

Comment: @TomFenech here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649733/awk-command-to-add-and-delete-lines-from-a-bloc  another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484795/sed-or-awk-to-replace-a-line-in-a-block

Comment: @Jotne a similar principal if you know what you're doing but not quite the same. There's probably some that are much closer but they are difficult to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ sed  '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/{s~AllowOverride None~AllowOverride All~i}' file
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All //change this one
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/` used to pick those lines which falls within a range . `{s~AllowOverride None~AllowOverride All~i}` will do the replacement on those matched lines only.

Comment: btw what is the meaning of comma in this /,/

Comment: it acts like a range operator. from the line which satisfies the first pattern `/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/` `,` upto the line which matches the last pattern `/<\/Directory>/`

Comment: @AvinashRaj wy did you use `i` option? there is no sense with or without that.

Comment: `i`, case insensitive modifier.. I think you already hear about this.. for this example, we don't need that. But if op wants to do a case insensitive match, then he must need to add `i` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the address range in `sed` as

```
$ $ sed -e '\#<Directory /var/www/>#, \#</Directory># s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/i' input

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All //change this one
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
</Directory>
```

- `#<Directory /var/www/>#, \#</Directory>#` ensures that the action is taken only for lines within the start pattern `Directory /var/www/>` and end pattern `</Directory>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` with `RS=`:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/ {
            sub(/AllowOverride None/, "AllowOverride All")} 1' file
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All //change this one
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Using `RS=` will set record separator to empty string giving us each `<Directory>...</Directory>` block in each record. Then it is just matter of matching a record with `<Directory /var/www/>` and simple replacing using `sub`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/^<\Directory>.$/s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g'
```

Find a pattern across multiple lines

```
<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/^<\Directory>.$
```

Find every group of lines starting with `<Directory /var/www/>` and ending with with a line that has only `</Directory>`

Afterwards substitute `AllowOverride All` for `AllowOverride None` in each pattern group.

**Output**

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All //change this one
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
</Directory>
```